# How to insert a button in a movable javascript element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I would like to put the button in the movable element js; I do not know how to start, I'm a beginner and I wasnt able to find a solution.

How can I insert a button with a function call in a movable js element?

Here is a example:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmUcU.png)

And some js code:

```
var pos = $('#center').position(),
radiusSat = $('#sat1').width() * 0.5,
radius = $('#center').width() * 0.5,
cx = pos.left + radius,
cy = pos.top + radius,
x, y, angle = 0, angles = [],
spc = 360 / 5,
deg2rad = Math.PI / 180,
i = 0;

for(;i < 5; i++) {
angles.push(angle);
angle += spc;
}

`/// space out radius`
radius += (radiusSat + 10);

loop();

function loop() {

for(var i = 0; i < angles.length; i++) {

    angle = angles[i];

    x = cx + radius * Math.cos(angle * deg2rad);
    y = cy + radius * Math.sin(angle * deg2rad);

    $('#sat' + i).css({left:x - radiusSat, top:y - radiusSat});

    angles[i] = angles[i] + 1;
    if (angles[i] > 360) angles[i] = 0;
}

requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/F8x4p/

Comment: Do you want to add the buttons when you click on the #sat divs or what is the expected functionality?

Comment: I want to create moving buttons in this moving js structure. On each click on the buttons another function should be generate random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert a button on the even sat elements.
After the buttons are in the DOM, you can select them and add event listeners. If you want to add the same listener for each button, you can follow my example. If you want a different listener, select the button by class `$('.btn-' + index')`.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andreiTn/F8x4p/1360/

Answer (score -1):

Just put a button inside the div tags or replace your divs with an a tag :)

```
<div id="sat0"><button>Hi</button></div>
<a class="link" href="#" id="sat1">Hi</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rakowu/F8x4p/1330/

Comment: Ok sorry, i didn't understood it right :) 

Do you use jquery? In this case you can use append with in each or for loop.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, im using jQuery.I would like to generate another js function by clicking on the buttons. Its not related with link button.

Comment: Ok, i hope i could help :)